# I have to iterate some if-else conditions for each row in data-frame in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to iterate some `if-else` conditions for each row in `dataframe` in `python`.

If the first condition is satisfied for `row1`, it will answer 'yes' or 'no' by adding one more column for that row and exit.

But if for the `row 2`, with another other condition satisfied, it shouldn’t overwrite the first row’s ‘yes’ or ‘no’.

I want it to be preserved or we can say in second iteration it should check all if else conditions for only `row2` and then `row3` and so on.

To be precise, only one row will be check against all the condition and which ever condition satisfy, it will give the output by adding one more column for that row and exit. [image: input and output]

I am new to `python` and the code I wrote is not working.

I have written the below code. Kindly help me.

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():

if row['Resolution Summary'].str.contains("\\bHardware failure\\b", case = False) :
    df['flag'] = np.where(data['Resolution Summary'].str.contains("\\bHardware failure\\b", case = False), 'yes','')

    elif row['Resolution Summary'].str.contains("\\brouter\\b", case = False):
        df['flag'] = np.where(data['Resolution Summary'].str.contains("\\brouter\\b", case = False), 'yes','')
```

Comment: Based on the question title, missing desired output and missing input it is unclear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Also please read the documentation on "how to ask".  Punctuation and formatting *really* matter. Why would anyone waste so much time just to figure out what you are trying to ask, when you don't put the effort in to communicate clearly, or care to respect the time of volunteers. Plenty of other questions we can look at. I understand your new to the community. Welcome. Please `edit` your question to boost your chances of receiving a timely, good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to iterate rows explicitly. In fact, you shouldn't need to calculate the same Boolean values multiple times.

If you wish to prioritise a particular assignment given a condition, you can do so explicitly. Here's one way using `numpy.where`; we use `~` to indicate "negative".

```
mask1 = df['Resolution Summary'].str.contains("\\bHardware failure\\b", case = False)
mask2 = df['Resolution Summary'].str.contains("\\brouter\\b", case = False)

df['flag'] = np.where(mask1, 'yes', '')
df['flag'] = np.where(mask2 & ~mask1, 'yes', df['flag'])
```

Of course, in this very trivial case, you can just use one condition:

```
df['flat'] = np.where(mask1 | mask2, 'yes', '')
```